# View not updating after changing value of component array

Tags: angular5

I need to update my view on changing array in my *.component.ts
I use

```
public getFolders() : void {
    this.webService.getFolders({client_id : this.local.get('clientUser').client_id}).subscribe( this.processSkills.bind(this, this.local.get('clientUser')))
}

processSkills(res: any, myobj): void {
    if(res.status){
        myobj.folders = res.folders;
        this.local.set('clientUser', myobj);
        this.userObj = this.local.get('clientUser');
    }
}
```

It updates my array i saw in console it update my session value which i saw after pressing F5 but it doesn't update my view

Initially i am assigning my array to variable from my session object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(this.local.get('clientUser'));
currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
```

I resolved it and found a solution to pass our array into session and make the code into our provider which works as observable to my array and then recieve

> currentMessage to our receiver function to update on view.

```
this.webService.currentMessage.subscribe(message => {
    this.userObj = message;
})
```

will receive updated value and will reflect on view.